# Why do threads present inconsistent results? -Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have this code:

```
import threading
import time

#Starting a timer
start = time.time()


def zero():
    for i in range(0,10):
        print(0)


def one():
    for i in range(0,10):
        print(1)


#threads
t0 = threading.Thread(target=zero)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=one)

t0.start()
t1.start()

#To run the threads before any thing bellow.
t0.join()
t1.join()

end = time.time()
print(f"The program took {round(end - start,3)} seconds to finish.")
```

**RESULTS:**

(0): 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

(1): 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

(2): 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1

**Shouldn't it be 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1?**

**EDIT:**

Thanks, it was answered by this: [Execution order of multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228164/execution-order-of-multiple-threads)

And:
[What makes the execution order of threads unpredictable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915337/what-makes-the-execution-order-of-threads-unpredictable)

And the comments too.

Comment: Threads run independently of one another. They don't alternate. There is a certain amount of variance in how their execution will progress, due to many external factors. Generally, you can not at all predict where one thread will be in its execution based on your position in the execution of another thread.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228164/execution-order-of-multiple-threads) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915337/what-makes-the-execution-order-of-threads-unpredictable) should be able to help you.

Comment: @JohnPaulR but the idea of threads is not for running something when another thing is not running? So when the first print is done, shouldn't it move to another one, and so on? It's something wrong here?

Comment: When you spawn two different threads, you are, in a way, starting two new programs. At least, two sets of instructions that execute at the same time, and are unaware of each other. It would be like if you started two python scripts in 2 different terminals. They both run at the same time, without waiting for each other.

Comment: @JohnPaulR Ah, it's much clear now. Thank you R.

Comment: @g_odim_3, the thread does not sleep when first print is done.

Comment: @JohnPaulR but how can I run one(),  only but only, the zero() prints something (then moves to one(), then again zero() and so on)?

Comment: ~Do you need to use threads? This seems like a place where threads would be very inefficient.~ Edit: One moment

Comment: @JohnPaulR I would like to run a function() only when another is finished and so on (multiple times). I thought threads would do that.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is indeed a way to do this using threads, but I don't remember the exact method. From briefly reading the [python docs on threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), thread conditions or locks might help here.

Comment: Depending on what it is you need, [this method](https://pastebin.com/gNTLahH0) might better suit what you are trying to do. (and is much simpler than managing threads)